# Runnable из view.post(runnable) запускается очень нескоро

Tags: android, gui

У меня в активити один фрагмент-контейнер. При запуске приложения в этот контейнер вставляется мой основной фрагмент (`CalendarFragment`). В нем есть `ViewPager`, внутри которого - кастомные `View` (`MonthView`)- календарь на месяц. При создании каждого используется метод `view.post(Runnable)`.

При первоначальной загрузке `CalendarFragment` во `Viewpager` создается 3 `MonthView` и сразу запускаются `run()` из `Runnable` из `post()`. В общем, в видимом `MonthView` все чудесно отрисовывается.

Если же далее мы с помощью `fragmentManager.add()` добавляем другой фрагмент, а после убираем его при помощи `fragmentManager.popBackStack()`, то первоначальный `CalendarFragment` начинает заново запускать свой `onCreateView()`. `Viewpager` создается 3 `MonthView`. При этом в каждом `MonthView` запускается `view.post(Runnable)`. Но `run()` из этих `Runnable` не запускается, сколько бы мы не ждали - вместо `MonthView` - пустое место. `run()` запускается только когда начинаем листать `ViewPager`, и только тогда картинка отрисовывается.

Что препятствует немедленному запуску `run()` во втором случае, и как добиться, чтобы картинка сразу отрисовывалась при возвращении к первоначальному фрагменту?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ - как и где запускается `Runnable`:

В методе `instatiateItem() PagerAdapter` вызываем `monthView.initViewGroup()`.

```
public void initViewGroup() {

    final TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    final TextView view = (TextView) ((TableRow)tableLayout.getChildAt(4)).getChildAt(3);

    // Расчет ширины, высоты элемента и размера шрифта
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run is launched");
            int width = view.getWidth();
            int height = view.getHeight();
            ...
            float textSizePX = (int) (INITIAL_TEXT_SIZE * coeff);

            setSizesAndText(tableLayout, width, height, textSizePX);
            setDaysDecoration(tableLayout);

        }
    };

    view.post(runnable);
}
```

Comment: покажите, как и где вы запускаете Runnable

Comment: @metalurgus Вопрос дополнен

Comment: а initViewGroup когда вызывается? Я пытаюсь понять, нет ли у вас там какого-то if ненужного. Можете попробовать еще вместо  `view.post(runnable);`  использовать `new Handler().post(runnable);`

Comment: Ненужного условия вроде нет. А Handler мне не подошел. При его использовании неточно рассчитываются размеры элемента. Наверное,  он срабатывает (берет пробные размеры элемента) в какой-то неудачный момент. Но, правда, пустого места при возвращении из другого фрагмента не бывает.

Comment: Вы, возможно, удивитесь, но `View.post()` внутри выполняет `Handler.post()`. Разница только в используемом` Handler`. но на размеры это влиять не должно, думаю, проблема в другом

Comment: @metalurgus Но ведь налицо отличие в работе по двум параметрам - другая картинка и пустое место для view.post(). Почему?

Comment: Наверно, в использовании другого, настроенного по-другому `Handler`. Но на рассчеты это никак не может повлиять.